# Let U be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, Show that $f(U)$ is open and $f^{-1}$ exists and it is differentiable.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I have this exercise:

> Let U be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and suppose that $f:U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a differentiable function such that $||I-f'(x)||\leq\frac{1}{2}$. Show that $f(U)$ is open and $f^{-1}$ exists and it is differentiable.

I know that if $V,W$ are normed vectorial spaces and $L(V;W)$ is the set of continous linear transformations from $V$ to $W$, the function $||\cdot||:L(V;W)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by  $||T||=\sup_{x\in V\\||x||_V=1}||T(x)||_W$ for each $T\in L(V;W)$, is a norm over the space $L(V;W)$. I suspect that this is useful, but i don't know how to start, can yo give me a hint, or a way or something, please?

Comment: Sounds like you need to use the inverse function theorem.

Comment: Hint: $\|(x-f(x))-(y-f(y))\| \leq \frac 12  \|x-y\|$.

Comment: @MarkSaving I know implicitly that, but to use it i haven't $f'$ is continuous and pointly invertible yet

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I understand that this is equivalent to my hypotesis $||I-f'(x)||\leq\frac{1}{2}$ but i going back to the same point that i was.